# append public path to url('address') in scss file using Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have developed a single page web application.

The problem is that path of image file is defined in absolute way.

Therefore, I tried to add './public' to those path, which means that image file is under the public folder.(On local development environment I use proxy to handle such situation and on environment of production server the proxy can not be used)

[ex) url('/image/headers/picture.png'),which is written in a scss file=> url('./public/image/headers/picture.png'), which is transpile to bundle.js file]

I thought that it would be easily solved by using file-loader or url-loader to webpack.configure file like this:

```
output:{
    publicPath:'./public'
}
module:{
    loaders:[
        {test:/\.(|png|gif)$/,loader:'file-loader'}
    ]
}
```

However when I opened bundle.js file, publicPath is not added to the original image path. I tried to use resolve-url-loader but it is only for the similar case of relative path.

Thank you for your attention and I am new to webpack . I've looked at other similar questions with no luck so sorry if this feels like its been asked